# How to display grouped data using flexbox and *ngFor

Tags: arrays, json, angular, flexbox

I have a list of objects that I want to display based on parent-child relation using flexbox with *ngFor.

How can I loop the **people** and display each person in a flexbox div below each **countries** row?

Here is the flexbox example code:

**.html**

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="flex-container">
    <div>Country</div>
    div>Language</div>
    <div>Products</div>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-data" *ngFor="let c of dataCountry">
    <div>{{c.country}}</div>
    <div>{{c.language}}</div>
    <div>{{c.product}}</div>
 </div>
....
</div>
```

**.ts**

```
dataCountry: any[] = [
    {
      "country": "Singapore",
      "language": "language",
      "product": "Airlines",
      'people': [
        {
          "name": "Chia Thye Poh",
          "age": "60"
        },
        {
          "name": "Joanna Dong",
          "age": "50"
        },
        {
          "name": "S Dhanabalan",
          "age": "82"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "country": "US",
      "aanguage": "Eng",
      "product": "Cars",
      'people': [
        {
          "name": "Day  Meyers",
          "age": "70"
        },
        {
          "name": "Aguirre  Ellis",
          "age": "50"
        },
        {
          "name": "Cook  Tyson",
          "age": "50"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I want to have other rows showing poeples data under each country rows.

Here is an example but using **ul and li**: [example](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngfor/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write another ngFor loop inside the ngFor loop

```
<div class="container">
<div class="flex-data" *ngFor="let c of dataCountry">
    <ul>
        <li>{{c.country}}
            <ul *ngFor="let people of c.people">
                <li>{{people.name}}</li>
                <li>{{people.age}}</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div>{{c.language}}</div>
    <div>{{c.product}}</div>
</div>
```

Here is stackbiz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5rzav1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I found a solution, but this looks cool too. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, please do you know how one can collapse/hide each country row, one at a time?

Comment: You can use of  variable and toggle that variable on click

Comment: Could you add an example to the demo you created, thanks?

Comment: Here you go
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5rzav1

Comment: That looks great! But please and please, how do I go about it if I want to toggle the whole div. That the div with class "flex-box". That is, if I click US it hide all the data. I want exactly what you did on the li, but for the whole div. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: You just need to modify the toggle function.
 here you go
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5rzav1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
If it helps do upvote comment and answer

Comment: Thanks alot, nice one!

Comment: Hi, could you help me with mat-icon toggle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64498898/how-to-toggle-mat-icon-add-remove-angular-material